# Enabling cross-origin isolation on the apache2 web server

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, sharedarraybuffer

My system is Ubuntu and i use the apache2 web server. I need SharedArrayBuffer in my site. But when I call my page I get the error:

```
"Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: SharedArrayBuffer is not defined"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I did some research and quickly found out that I had to add the following to the header:

```
Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin
Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy: require-corp
```

Now digging further.

in the console:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

and changed AllowOverride None in AllowOverride All

```
<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All       
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

enabled mod headers

```
sudo a2enmod headers
```

then i restarted the apache2 server

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

created in var/www:

.htaccess

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin
Header set Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy: require-corp
```

So now I have a cross origin isolated page.

Comment: Specifying `Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` allows all origins. You should specify the origin.  Do not use wildcards for origin otherwise, you have a CORS policy that protects nothing.

Comment: You're right! At first I was just happy to have finally managed to do it after a long time. All in all, I learned a lot from it. Now I can make it specific instead "*"